# How to add a custom icon to MessageBox?

Tags: vb6

How can I use my own icon (like `vbexclamation`) with the `MsgBox()` method? I need to add a icon of my own.

Answer (score 5):

I don't believe `MsgBox()` supports this. You would need to create your own Form from scratch as a replacement for `MsgBox()`.

Answer (score 0):

There is an Extended Msgbox project at http://rpgprojects.homestead.com/code.html

Also, take a look at http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?329373-MsgBoxEx-Extended-Message-Box